# Need Detailed Error in json schema validation Python

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have below json schema, i want to use python's  library to validate the input json against given schema, it's using draft-08 version i.e., 2019-09. so i tried using below code for the same but it does not gives error in detail, for ex. in provided sample input resending is of type boolean so it should give error as this is not of type boolean but instead code gives error as <[{'entityType': 'default', 'function': '01', 'resending': 'False', 'afdDefinitionName': 'example', 'originalMessageId': '12345'}] does not contain items matching the given schema>

schema:

```html
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
    "description": "my schema",
    "definitions": {
      "BCCI": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "entityType": {
            "description": "",
            "type": "string",
            "const": "default"
          },
          "function": {
            "description": "",
            "codelistName": "ADNFUN",
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "const": "01"
              },
              {
                "const": "02"
              },
              {
                "const": "09"
              },
              {
                "const": "54"
              }
            ]
          },
          "resending": {
            "description": "",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "afdDefinitionName": {
            "description": "",
            "customDescription": "",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "originalMessageId": {
            "description": "",
            "customDescription": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "entityType",
          "function",
          "afdDefinitionName"
        ]
      }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "BCCI": {
        "type": "array",
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "allOf": [
          {
            "minContains": 1,
            "maxContains": 1,
            "contains": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/BCCI"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "BCCI"
    ]
  }
```

json Input:

```html
{
    "BCCI": [
        {
            "entityType": "default",
            "function": "01",
            "resending": "false",
            "afdDefinitionName": "example",
            "originalMessageId": "12345"
        }
    ]
}
```

Code used:

```html
import json
import jsonschema
from jsonschema import validate, validators, Draft7Validator, Draft201909Validator, Draft202012Validator
from jsonschema.exceptions import ValidationError

json_file = 'path to json instance'
json_schema_file = 'path to json schema instance'

with open(json_file) as f:
    document = json.load(f)

with open(json_schema_file) as f:
    schema = json.load(f)

errors = []
try:
    validate(instance=document, schema=schema)
except jsonschema.exceptions.ValidationError as e:
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    print(e)
    print("----------------------------------------------------------")
    
    print(f"Error message: {e.message}")
    print(f"Error tag: {e.json_path}")
    print(f"Error tag: {list(e.path)}")
    print(f"Definition: {e.validator}")
```

output:

```html
----------------------------------------------------------
[{'entityType': 'default', 'function': '01', 'resending': 'false', 'afdDefinitionName': 'example', 'originalMessageId': '12345'}] does not contain items matching the given schema

Failed validating 'contains' in schema['properties']['BCCI']['allOf'][0]:
    {'contains': {'$ref': '#/definitions/BCCI'},
     'maxContains': 1,
     'minContains': 1}

On instance['BCCI']:
    [{'afdDefinitionName': 'example',
      'entityType': 'default',
      'function': '01',
      'originalMessageId': '12345',
      'resending': 'false'}]
----------------------------------------------------------
Error message: [{'entityType': 'default', 'function': '01', 'resending': 'false', 'afdDefinitionName': 'example', 'originalMessageId': '12345'}] does not contain items matching the given schema
Error tag: $.BCCI
Error tag: ['BCCI']
Definition: contains
```

it should have printed about boolean issue, or if there was any other issue with input json but it does not gives error in detail.

Comment: _it should have printed about boolean issue_ Are you saying that you **want** it to print a detailed message, or are you saying that's what it  actually **should** have done?

Comment: Yeah it should have printed the error in detail but it has not printed

Comment: Can you provide a link to documentation where it says it should have done that?

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. below is the link for one of the online json schema validation where you need to input schema and your json instance, after validation it gives proper detailed error the same I want to achieve in python, here currently what is happening it just gives generic error not the detailed error like why it is failed in validation.
 
https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/

Comment: Okay, so some website gives a detailed error message.  That doesn't mean the `jsonschema` module is necessarily supposed to do the same thing.  I'll ask again -- why are you **expecting** a detailed error message?  Can you point to actual `jsonschema` documentation that demonstrates this behavior?

Comment: please do not waste your valuable time, if you can't understand or provide the solution for it, i have already achieved it using draft7validator in jsonschema which gives detailed error message but that used draft-07 schema, but i have schema version of draft-08 where we have keywords such as minContains/maxContains/Contains which are not working with draft7validator. so posted question here if same has been faced by others as well, so they could provide the solution

Comment: @JohnGordon
below code gives detailed error message when i removed keywords such as minContains/maxContains/Contains

v = Draft201909Validator(schema)

for rec in document:
    temp = rec.get("error", [])
    errors = sorted(v.iter_errors(rec), key=lambda e: e.path)
    for error in errors:
        print("json_path list:", list(error.path))
        print("error_message:", error.message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with the keywords being used in draft-08 version that is why it was not giving proper detailed error, please use Items/minItems/maxItems instead of contains/minContains/maxContains in your schema then your code will work, below is the updated code which i am using which gives error in detail for all the errors for one particular json instance.

```html
import json
from jsonschema import  Draft201909Validator

json_file = 'test.json'
json_schema_file = 'test_schema.json'

with open(json_file) as f:
    document = json.load(f)

with open(json_schema_file) as f:
    schema = json.load(f)

v = Draft201909Validator(schema)

for rec in document:
    temp = rec.get("error", [])
    errors = sorted(v.iter_errors(rec), key=lambda e: e.path)
    for error in errors:
        print("---------------------------------------")
        print("json_path list:", list(error.path))
        print("error_message:", error.message)
```

updated json input schema:

```html
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema#",
    "description": "my schema",
    "definitions": {
      "BCCI": {
        "type": "object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties": {
          "entityType": {
            "description": "",
            "type": "string",
            "const": "default"
          },
          "function": {
            "description": "",
            "codelistName": "XXXXXX",
            "type": "string",
            "oneOf": [
              {
                "const": "01"
              },
              {
                "const": "02"
              },
              {
                "const": "09"
              },
              {
                "const": "54"
              }
            ]
          },
          "resending": {
            "description": "",
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "afdDefinitionName": {
            "description": "",
            "customDescription": "",
            "type": "string"
          },
          "originalMessageId": {
            "description": "",
            "customDescription": "",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "entityType",
          "function",
          "afdDefinitionName"
        ]
      }
    },
    "type": "object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties": {
      "BCCI": {
        "type": "array",
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "items": {
            "$ref": "#/definitions/BCCI"
          },
          "minItems": 1,
          "maxItems": 1
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "BCCI"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: `draft-08` isn't a thing anymore, it's now called `Draft 2019-09`